# Using IF AND OR all together..?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to filter a spread sheet that has multiple rows that are not needed unless the comply with certain criteria. The problem is that I keep getting the #VALUE! error. Specifically this is what I want

IF DHR!E10="Payment Processed" AND DHR!F10="completed" OR IF DHR!E10="subscription payment completed" AND DHR!F10="completed" THEN DHR!A10 otherwise "".

Then DHR!E10 has to equal "Payment Processed" or "subscription payment completed"
     DHR!F10 has to always equal "completed"
This is what I did:

```
=IF(OR(IF(AND(DHR!E10="Payment Processed",DHR!F10="completed"),DHR!A10,"")=DHR!A10,(IF(AND(DHR!E10="subscription payment completed",DHR!F10="completed"),DHR!A10,"")))=DHR!A10,DHR!A10,"")
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If I understand your logic it can be simplified to `=if(and(or(DHR!E10="Payment Processed" ,DHR!E10="subscription payment completed"),DHR!F10="completed"),DHR!A10 ,"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner - There we go again! :) Posting at the same time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, no:

`=IF(AND(DHR!F10="Completed",OR(DHR!E10="Subscription Payment Complete",DHR!E10="Payment Processed")),DHR!A10,"")`

Comment: Was just about to say "Copy Cat!"

Comment: Hahahaha! @ScottCraner. Great Scott's Think Alike! (wow that has a double-entendre, and I didn't even realize it!)